# Django test fails to create correct test DB, even main DB works fine

Tags: django, testing, migration

I have app "Invoice" with two models "Invoice" and "InvoicePDFTemplate". I wanted to add fields "terms" on both of them. With model Invoice everything went good, but I have problems with PDFTemplates:

makemigrations and migrate worked fine - new column was created in DB, I successfully developed code needed.

but when i ran `test invoice` - it failed as it seems that tests DB does not apply correctly migrations:

```
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column invoice_invoicepdftemplate.terms does not exist
LINE 1: ...fault", "invoice_invoicepdftemplate"."is_active", "invoice_i...
```

I've tried to change fields, delete migrations and recreate it. It does not solve the problem. I cannot understand why one model works fine and other does not.
And I cannot skip test as it is a part of CI/CD.

could you suggest any solution?

Comment: The line `Using existing test database` leads me to think that you're running your tests with a flag like `--keepdb` (in ./manage.py test) or `--reuse-db` (in pytest). These flags speed up testing by NOT creating a fresh database. But if your database schema changes, you need to recreated the database so that the schema is correct. Try removing the `--keepdb` or `--reuse-db` flag.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not the case

Comment: It is recreated everytime and to be sure I've dropped tables on both of them

Comment: Can you post the code that your CI/CD pipeline runs, specifically the line of code that runs the testing? I want to make sure there aren't any other flags that could be causing problems